# Get current y value location on screen of each UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, transparent, alpha

I have a `UITableViewController` with a custom class for my `UITableViewCell`. I have a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` on this `UITableViewCell`.

I want the content on the `UITableViewCell` to become a bit more translucent/transparent when it is above a certain y value on the screen, so you get a "fading effect", similar to the Rdio app:

[image: The alpha value of the <code>UIImageView</code> and UILabel are 1.0]
[image: Now the value is lower, like 0.7 or something.]

MyUIViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
```

MyUIViewController.m

```
@synthesize tableview;

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    NSArray *listOfVisibleCells = tableview.visibleCells;

    for (int i=0; i<[listOfVisibleCells count]; i++) {

        MTTableViewCell *cell = [listOfVisibleCells objectAtIndex:i];

        /* Smooth fade out */
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > (cell.frame.origin.y + 10)) {
            [cell.companyImage setAlpha:0.7];
        }
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > (cell.frame.origin.y + 20)) {
            [cell.companyImage setAlpha:0.5];
        }
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > (cell.frame.origin.y + 30)) {
            [cell.companyImage setAlpha:0.3];
        }
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > (cell.frame.origin.y + 40)) {
            [cell.companyImage setAlpha:0.1];
        }

        /* Fade in */
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < (cell.frame.origin.y + 10)) {
            [cell.companyImage setAlpha:1.0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

`if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > ((i*90)+30) ) {`

should be:

`if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > (cell.frame.origin.y + 30)) {`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you can use UITableView Delegate methods to handle these.

UITableViewDelegate :

Tells the delegate the table view is about to draw a cell for a particular row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

UIScrollViewDelegate :

Tells the delegate when the user scrolls the content view within the receiver.You can also know the content offset.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Following these methods,you can detect current UITableViewCell or the offset.y value.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: in the scrollViewDidScroll method, use `visibleCells` method on the tableView to get all currently visible cells onscreen. Each of those cells will have a specific y offset via `cell.frame.origin.y` which you can use for your fading effect.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have received your desired answer, I will add an alternate way to do this.

In your `scrollViewDidScroll:` method:

```
if ([myTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows].count) {

    NSIndexPath* firstCellIndexPath = [myTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows].firstObject;

    CGRect cellRect = [myTableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:firstCellIndexPath];//frame of cell with respect to the table content

    CGFloat yOriginForTopCell = [myTableView convertRect:cellRect toView:self.view].origin.y;//get y-origin after converting the co-ordinates to self.view

    NSLog(@"%f", yOriginForTopCell);
}
```

Here, you get the y-origin of the very first visible cell inside the table irrespective of the scroll state. Once you get your origin, you can use it in whatever way you like. Advantage being, no calculations required on your end. Just choose a value for your top edge (where fading must begin) preferably your topBar/navBar y-origin + height, which turns out to be a constant value.

You may set your alpha dynamically, with a more gradual fade with:

```
customCell* yourCell = (customCell*)[myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:firstCellIndexPath];

yourCell.yourView.alpha = yOriginForTopCell/<CONSTANT_VALUE>;//yourCell = `MTTableViewCell` | yourView = `companyImage`
```

Here your CONSTANT_VALUE should preferably be 64px(if using native UINavigationBar) or `yourTopBar.frame.origin.y + yourTopBar.frame.size.height` (if using a custom view at the top).

Try this solution for once.